# facebook api (post) picture and source do not work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with using facebook api (post function)

I tried to post to my page and it done successfully, but the problem that 'picture' and 'source' arguments do not appear in the wall post.

this is my code, can any one help me to make picture and source appear successfully.
and how can I perform

```
$params = array('appId'  => '674','secret' => 'fe3e',);
        $this->load->library('facebook',$params);
        // Get User ID
     $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        $page_id = 'dsht.wd';
        $page_info = $this->facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
        if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {

            $args = array(
                'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
                'message'       => "أحلى صدفة",
                'link'      => 'http://www.d-sht.com/',
                'caption'   => 'قابلتك صدفة',
                 'picture' =>'http://www.shorouknews.com/uploadedimages/Caricature/Amr%20Sleem/original/amr-selim-1144-(2).jpg',
                'name'=>'عنوان المقال',
                'source'=> 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umlJJFVgYVI'

            );
            $post_id = $this->facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
        }
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }
        if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {

      echo $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
    }
```

and how can I process this line (last line of my code)

```
$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
```

I tried to use `file_get_contents` but it does not work

**Note** : I used `rawurlencode($pic)` with 'picture' and it does not work

Comment: Do you want to post a link to a picture or a video on youtube? Or do you want to upload an image?

Comment: just attach a link to a picture. I do not need upload any thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should drop the "source" attribute (if it's just a picture, why would you point to a video?), change the "link" attribute to point to the actual picture and please encode the message, name and caption attributes.

When you share a link, especially since this would be a link to the picture, the thumbnail will be automatically displayed, so you don't have to worry about it.